# Open html help documentation pages for multiple functions simultaneously in R

Tags: r, list, function, plyr

I am using `plyr` package. Through `ls()` function I retrieved the below functions

```
    library(plyr)
    ls("package:plyr",pattern="ply")
    #  [1] "a_ply"    "aaply"    "adply"    "alply"    "d_ply"    "daply"   
    #  [7] "ddply"    "dlply"    "l_ply"    "laply"    "ldply"    "liply"   
    # [13] "llply"    "m_ply"    "maply"    "mdply"    "mlply"    "r_ply"   
    # [19] "raply"    "rdply"    "rlply"    "tryapply"
```

How can I open help documentation for all the above functions simultaneously in `html` from console using `help()` or any other function.

I tried using `c()` inside `help()` by putting few functions. It doesn't work. I also tried `list()` and then `help()`. Not sure how to go about it.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply`

```
lapply(ls("package:plyr",pattern="ply"), help)
```

Comment: I cant see any pages opening up in html. I tried `lapply` too. Give me a minute

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  In my system (windows 10), many pages opened simultaneously

Comment: `R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)`
`Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`
`Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)`

Comment: WHich system are you using?

Comment: The only remaining thing is, pages are now opening in browser but in console, it prints indexes like `[[1]]` `[[2]]` .... `[[22]]` , because there were 22 functions in the list

Comment: I made a slight addition including `invisible()`. Now its opening pages and not printing anything on console.
`invisible(capture.output(lapply(ls("package:plyr",pattern="ply"), help)))`

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  With the capture.output, I am not getting any pages

Comment: Which machine, you using?

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  I am using windows 10, R 3.3.1  i.e. `version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 10586)`

Comment: Not sure then whats the problem. Your code didnt give me any error as such but it didnt open the pages. When I put `capture.output()`. It does and when I remove `invisible()`, then it prints on console the indexes.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  I don't know if there are any firewalls installed in my system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125670/discussion-between-sowmya-s-manian-and-akrun).